# Custom text macros in Xcode not getting invoked with control-dot

Tags: xcode, macros

I created an "ObjectiveC.xctxtmacro" file in ~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Specifications with the code bellow. I see "Hello" in Xcode's Edit>Insert Text Macros>Objective-C menu item but when I try to invoke it using control-dot, nothing happens. Any ideas?

```
(
    {
        Identifier = objc.hello;
        BasedOn = objc;
        IsMenuItem = YES;
        Name = "Hello";
        TextString = "Hello, Xcode!";
        CompletionPrefix = "hello";
        IncludeContexts = ("xcode.lang.objc");
    }
)
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add an *OnlyAtBOL* specification to your macro.

Try this:

```
(
    {
        Identifier = objc.hello;
        BasedOn = objc;
        OnlyAtBOL = YES;
        IsMenuItem = YES;
        Name = "Hello";
        TextString = "Hello, Xcode!";
        CompletionPrefix = "hello";
        IncludeContexts = ("xcode.lang.objc");
    }
)
```

I am pretty new at text macros, but as far as i understand OnlyAtBOL means that this text macro will complete only when it is at the beggining of the line (**YES**) or not (**NO**).

It seems weird that it does not work without this specification, i don' t know if it' s a bug or feature :)

You might want to check this topic, since its probably the same thing you are trying to do:
http://forums.pragprog.com/forums/104/topics/3334